# In db2 on cloud Lite version, is it possible to export sql query results to csv? How?

Tags: csv, db2, export, ibm-cloud, weka

How do I export results of an sql query as a csv using db2 on cloud Lite version?  Is it possible, or is a paid level required for this?   I found the link in the results field “export to csv” but when I clicked on it, nothing happened.  Similarly, in the query field on the left side of the screen there is a link to export to csv, but that didn’t work either.  I would like to export to a form that can be used in WEKA.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Db2 on Cloud Lite and I can confirm that it works. I am using the **Run SQL** dialog to query the database. The button to actually run a query is a dropdown where you can choose to run the selected statement and export the result to a CSV or XLSX (Excel) file.

The export action is handled like a regular download. Depending on the browser you may see a pop-up or just a file in your download directory.